# Earth mover/Wasserstein distance between a pdf and an empirical distribution

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, optimal-transportation

This question is inspired by this much older question:

[Convergence of an empirical distribution w.r.t. the Hellinger distance](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45320/convergence-of-an-empirical-distribution-w-r-t-the-hellinger-distance)

Let $P$ be a continuous probability distribution on a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and let $X_1,X_2,…,X_n$ be drawn i.i.d. according to $P$. Define the empirical distribution:
$$\hat{P_n}(x) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} 1_{X_i = x}$$

Let $d(P,Q)$ denote the *earth-mover* distance between two distributions $P$ and $Q$.  Is there a nice expression for the expected distance between $\hat{P_n}$ and $P$?

Answer (score 1):

See, e.g., section 2.1 of http://arxiv.org/pdf/1209.1077.pdf; also http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02213456, which is cited in Villani's book as having particularly precise estimates.

Comment: Looking at the paper you cite, it seems that that paper cites an earlier work for the $W_1$ distance, which I think is the "earth-mover distance": [11] V. Dobri and J. Yukich. Asymptotics for transportation cost in high dimensions.
Journal of Theoretical Probability, 8:97-118, 1995.